# Function userHasVisitedAllParksInState

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

```
const parks = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Acadia",
      areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
      location: { state: "Maine" },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Canyonlands",
      areaInSquareKm: 1366.2,
      location: { state: "Utah" },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Crater Lake",
      areaInSquareKm: 741.5,
      location: { state: "Oregon" },
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Lake Clark",
      areaInSquareKm: 10602,
      location: { state: "Alaska" },
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Kenai Fjords",
      areaInSquareKm: 2710,
      location: { state: "Alaska" },
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Zion",
      areaInSquareKm: 595.9,
      location: { state: "Utah" },
    },
  ];

  const users = {
    "karah.branch3": {
      visited: [1],
      wishlist: [4, 6],
    },
    "dwayne.m55": {
      visited: [2, 5, 1],
      wishlist: [],
    },
    thiagostrong1: {
      visited: [5],
      wishlist: [6, 3, 2],
    },
    "don.kim1990": {
      visited: [2, 6],
      wishlist: [1],
    },
  };
```

I need to write a function `userHasVisitedAllParksInState` that does: This function returns a boolean that represents whether or not a user has visited all parks in the parks array from a given state.

I don't have any code for this because I don't even know where to start. Every time I think I have an idea it falls apart. Any help is appreciated.

```
function userHasVisitedAllParksInState(parks, users, state, userId) {}
```

Comment: Welcome Jesse. Could you include some of the ideas you tried? Otherwise, the question may be closed due to "not showing enough effort" or "too broad".

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Apologies, I've never used the site before so I was unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of ways you can solve this, but here are two ideas that you can continue developing:

One solution is very simple that works if you can't have visited the same park more than once. Create a list of the parks that match the requested state and check if the length of that is the same as the number of parks the person visited.

```
function userHasVisitedAllParksInState(parks, users, state, userId) {
  var parksForState = parks.filter((park) => park.location.state === state);
  return users[userId].visited.length === parksForState.length;
}
```

Another solution that might be easier to understand and works even if you have duplicate entries in the visited arrays:

```
function userHasVisitedAllParksInState1(parks, users, state, userId) {
  var user = users[userId];
  var parksForState = parks.filter((park) => park.location.state === state);
  // Assume the person did visit all to start
  var visitedAll = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < parksForState.length; i++) {
    // If the park we're checking atm is in the visited array, we've still visited all parks. If parksForState[i].id is not in user.visited
    visitedAll = visitedAll && user.visited.indexOf(parksForState[i].id) > -1;
  }
  return visitedAll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first answer is more my speed as I haven't actually learned about indexOf() in my program yet. This is very helpful.